# Rattling (sounds like a leaf or two) from furnace exhaust pipe

Tags: hvac, furnace

Up in my attic today, I noticed a rattling sound coming from the furnace exhaust pipe when the furnace is on. It sounds like a leaf or two rattling around. It is at the lower part of the exhaust tubing. The tubing turns up 90 degrees and then goes about 4-5 feet vertical to the roof.

[image]

I turned off the furnace and removed the hex nuts fastening the pipe to the furnace, but there isn't a lot of give to pull it away from the ring on the furnace that it surrounds, so I re-secured the pipe.

Is a single leaf or two cause for concern, or should I just leave it be? Is there a trick to removing the pipe to get the debris out? It is pretty securely attached in place up by the roof, and I don't want to cause damage to the pipe or the flashing trying to force it. (It reminds me of bad experiences recently trying to bend old brittle sprinkler PVC.) Is this beyond DIY and I should call an HVAC company? (Previous poor experiences make me reluctant, but if that's the best course, I'll do it.)

Here's a pic of the vent exiting the roof:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I would not want combustibles that close to a combustion source.

As others have said, you should be able to remove that elbow without too much trouble. A little lubrication on the sliding seams would help manipulate it out of position, and vice versa. All of the hemmed seams in such an elbow are designed to slide for a wide range of angles. Only remove the screws on the elbow, at least to start.

Or, if you'd rather not, drop a wet/dry vac hose down from the top and slurp it out. Just be sure to tape the hose extension together so it can't come apart in an unfortunate location.